# JavaScript program to find the greatest common divisor (gcd) of two positive numbers

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me understand this code?
I do not understand `!b` part

```
function gcd(a, b) {
   if ( ! b) {
      return a;
   }
   return gcd(b, a % b);   
}
```

Comment: `!b` is there as a condition to end this recursive function. Basically, once the argument passed in as `b` is `0`, `!b` resolves to `true` and `a` is returned

Comment: `!` is the logical NOT operator. It coerces the argument supplied to it to a boolean. The `Number` zero coerces to `false`, and `NOT(false)` is `true`. In effect it is a quick way of saying "if `b` is zero"

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code.

```
function gcd(a,b) {
  int r;
  while( 0 !== b) {
    r = a % b;
    a = b;
    b = r;
  }
  return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The greatest common divisor (if there is one), is the largest number that two numbers `a` and `b` can both be divided by, with a remainder of zero.

If `b` is zero, then the gcd is `a`.

If `b` is not zero, the gcd is the gcd of `b` and the remainder of `a/b`.

This is because the remainder needs to be eliminated in order to find the common factor, and the remainder can only be eliminated by a factor of itself.

Pseudocode:

```
def gcd a, b
  if b is zero
    return a
  else
    return gcd of b and remainder(a, b)
  end if
end def
```

Javascript:

```
function gcd(a, b) {
    if(b === 0) {
        return a;
    }
    return gcd(b, a % b)
}
```

...can also be written as:

```
function gcd(a, b) {
    if(!b) {
        return a;
    }
    return gcd(b, a%b)
}
```